# Connect to built in Microsoft SQL server in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using windows 10 with a microsoft account . I want to connect to Microsoft SQL server which is built in Visual Studio via asp.net .

I am using following :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Applicant Login</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

   
<body style="margin-left:30px"> 
    <div style="float:right">
         <img src="1.png"/>
    <br />
         <img src="2.png"/> 

 </div>
<div>
    <a href="Default.aspx" class="">Back</a>
</div>
    <br />
    <div >
        <h1 style="color:rgb(159,30,68)">Graduate Tracking System</h1>
        <br />
        Login as:
        <br />
        <br />
        <form runat="server">
            <div style="margin-bottom:30px">
                            <label class=" " style="margin-right:85px">ID :
               </label>
          <asp:TextBox TextMode="Email" CssClass="input-md form-inline " id="myid" Enabled="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
         
            <label style="margin-right:30px">Password :</label>
                <asp:TextBox TextMode="Password" id="mypass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     
                <br />
            <br />
            <input class="btn btn-md" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>

            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it does not show anything

Comment: what does not show anything? Do you have some code which actually makes use of this connection string? i.e. something that selects or updates? What happens when that code runs? Go into debug mode to check. I'll take a guess and say you have incorrectly used try/catch and the error is hidden, or an error occurs but you can't find it.

Comment: If you attached your database file in Visual studio server tab then just right click on that .mdf file ,select Properties and take connection Path

Comment: does not show anything? are you saying your web browser is blank? YOu need to explain the problem in more detail. Have you done any debugging? Try using F12 tools to verify that the page runs